# RecyclerView does not update a private field in onBindViewHolder after notifydatasetchanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter

I have a RecyclerView in which I have to load different data based on a value which I am changing in an updateList method.
Following is my code:

```
public class PerformanceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PerformanceAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Performance> list;
Context ctx;

int searchField;

public PerformanceAdapter(ArrayList list, Context ctx) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    this.list = list;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

public void updateList(ArrayList<Performance> list, int searchField) {
    this.searchField = searchField;
        ArrayList tempList = new ArrayList();
        tempList.addAll(list);
        Log.i("saz","Size on notifyupdate: "+list.size()+" and searchField: "+this.searchField);
        this.list.clear();
        this.list.addAll(tempList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public PerformanceAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_performance_cardview, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    searchField = viewType;
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PerformanceAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   /* position = (int) convertView.getTag();
    Log.i("saz","position value 2nd : "+position);*/
    Performance performance = this.list.get(position);
Log.i("saz","searchField: "+searchField);

    if (position%2 != 0) {
        holder.cv.setCardBackgroundColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.lighter_gray));
    } else {
        holder.cv.setCardBackgroundColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }

    Log.i("saz","searchField: "+searchField);
    holder.txtModelName.setText(performance.getModelName());
    if (searchField == 0) {
        holder.cv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (searchField == 1) {
        Log.i("saz","searchField: "+searchField);
        holder.cv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.cv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.cv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.cv4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else if (searchField == 2) {
        holder.cv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.cv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.cv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.cv4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return searchField;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.i("saz","List size in recycler: "+list.size());
    return this.list.size();
}
```

Then I call

```
updateList(list, 0)
updateList(list, 1)
or updateList(list, 2)
```

on click of a button.

But I always get the searchField as 0 in my bindViewHolder.
Please help.

Comment: Can you share the code that calls `updateList`? Do they go together with onNotify... function call?

Comment: No they do not goo together. They are called based on the spinner's selected item posion. The code is actually like updateList(list, spinner.getSelectedItemPosition).

Comment: Is the `list` always the same? What if you modify the `list` slightly when performing update?

Comment: The list content is changing every time I call updateList() method, but the data in recycler view doesn't reflect.

Comment: Can you alter the data a little to make it different when you update...  just to experiment if recyclerview is so smart that as long as the content is the same, it doesn't change itself, hence not picking up your latest viewType.

Comment: I am changing the data is the list already.

Answer (score 0):

You overriding it with viewType which is always 0 because there's only one type.

```
@Override public
PerformanceAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) { 
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.list_performance_cardview, parent, false); // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters 
    searchField = viewType; 
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v); 
    return vh;
}
```

Comment: the `viewType` comes from `getItemViewType` which is based on the updated `searchField`

Comment: @stas even if I remove my searchField overriding with itemViewType, I get the same result.

Comment: @Sarfazar Add one more notifyDataSetChanged just after 'this.list.clear();'

Comment: Looks like you're passing identical lists to adapter

Comment: Or simply override this.list with new array

Comment: No the list data is different. The only issue is searchField value is always 0 in my onBindView method. If it recieves 1 or 2 the list will update accordingly. Also the onBindView method is not called after notifydatasetchanged() is called

Comment: Just try to override this.list with new array